# Bash's conditional operator and assignment

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, arithmetic

Can we use bash's conditional operator with assignment operators after colon?

[Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) explains the arithmetic operators as follows.

- conditional operator `expr ? expr : expr`
- assignment `= *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= &= ^= |=`

First, this code seems to work well:

```
a=1; ((a? b=1 : 2 )) #seems to work
```

But when I use assignment operators after `:`, I got 'attempted assignment to non-variable' error:

```
a=1; ((a? b=1 : c=1)) #attempted assignment to non-variable error
```

Why can we use only assignment operators before colon?

Comment: It may be fun to perform variable assignments using the conditional operator but it'd make your code highly unreadable.  I'd prefer `((a)) && b=1 || c=1`

Comment: @devnull I think the code's readability depends most upon who reads it. Still, it may be true what you say, but I've tested `ternary` operators in `dash, zsh, sh`, and `bash` and they all behave the same, despite their not being specified by POSIX. Your example only works in `bash` and `zsh` as far as I know. However, this is POSIX friendly: `( : ${a?} ) && b=1 || c=1`. I also find it far easier to read than either `ternary` or your own example.

Answer (score 5):

Bash parses your last command as

```
a=1; (( (a? b=1 : c)=1 ))
```

which should make clear why it does not work. Instead you have to use

```
a=1; (( a? b=1 : (c=1) ))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a `ternary assignment` expression. Here's a bit from another answer of mine:

```
% a=abc
% b=abcd
% t=10 ; f=5
% echo $((r=${#a}>${#b}?t:f)) ; echo $r
> 5 
> 5
% echo $((r=${#a}<${#b}?t:f)) ; echo $r
> 10
> 10
```

You see, as you say, this is a *conditional* assignment operation. It depends upon conditions. The syntax works like this:

```
$((var = $condition <compare_operator> $condition \
    ?if $true_assign :or $false_assign ))
```

I don't believe you are using this correctly.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Conditional_assignment):

> `?:` is used as follows:
>
> > `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`
>
> The condition is evaluated true or false as a Boolean expression. On the basis of the evaluation of the Boolean condition, the entire expression returns value_if_true if condition is true, but value_if_false otherwise. Usually the two sub-expressions value_if_true and value_if_false must have the same type, which determines the type of the whole expression. The importance of this type-checking lies in the operator's most common use—in conditional assignment statements. In this usage it appears as an expression on the right side of an assignment statement, as follows:
>
> > `variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`
>
> The `?:` operator is similar to the way conditional expressions (`if-then-else` constructs) work in functional programming languages, like Scheme, ML, and Haskell, since if-then-else forms an expression instead of a statement in those languages.

I think your specific problem is related to this:

> > *As in the if-else construct only one of the expressions 'x' and 'y' are evaluated.*

If you read through the above link on `ternary` expressions you'll see that evaluation is short-circuited so your assignment on the *false* side errors because `1 = true`.

In any case, it doesn't matter too much because I don't think this does what you think it does.

Comment: As WP says, `$(())` can only contain arithmetic expressions and therefore, a general ternary assignment doesn't exist in Bash.

Comment: @zakmck i think you should check again. try the code in the example.

Comment: @mkeserv, I usually check before commenting, now your turn:
Works: echo $((1==2 ? 1 : 0)). Works, but accidentally: echo $((1==1 ? 1 : NO)). Doesn't work, evaluates $NO to 0, returns 0, not 'NO': echo $((1==2 ? 1 : NO)). Error: $((1==2 ? 1 : 'NO')). Error, "A" and "B" are evaluated to 0, result is 1: echo $(("A" == "B" ? 1 : 0)). The problem is $((x ? y : z)) is valid for numerical expressions only. Bash 5.1.8(1)

Comment: you cant assign to a number. the assigned variable has to be the first in the list. `$((no?1:2))` and of course the ternary is valid for mumericals only; its arithmetic.

Comment: the point is $(( ? : )) works when returning numbers only and the OP probably wants to know if such a ternary operator exists in general (as other say, it doesn't).

Comment: @zakmck but you do understand that ternary assignment in math works, just for numerics only. if `$(())` can return it then its a valid value to assign to a variable in a ternary expression.

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operators return a value based on a test.  They are not used for branching.

Here's one way to get a pseudo-ternary operator for bash (note the back-ticks):

> `` $result=`[ < condition > ] && echo "true-result" || echo "false-result" ` ``

`` $ a=
$ c=`[ $a ] && echo 1 || echo 0`
$ echo $c
0

$ a=5
$ c=`[ $a ] && echo 1 || echo 0`
$ echo $c
1 ``